# Express routes and middleware

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, routes, authorization

I'm using a role authorisation ([connect-roles](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/connect-roles)), and trying to add more than one role for each route. This is using express, and monogoose. Here is the code I currently have:

```
 router.get('/admin/:slug', function (req, res) {

   if (user.can('vip')) {

     adminController.showVipView // <-- this is what I need to work

   } else {

     // call a different view

   }

});
```

This is how it normally works without the if statement. This seems like super basic express, but I just cannot get it to work.

```
router.get('/admin/:slug', user.can('vip'), adminController.showVipView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `request` and `response` into it:

```
adminController.showVipView(req, res);
```

It might also requires the `next` callback, then you should pass that into it too...

By the way, your if statement wont work either as it returns a middleware. Might do this:

```
user.can('vip')(req, res, function(){
  adminController.showVipView(req, res);
});
```